# Is the root node of a singly linked list considered a part of the list?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

A singly-linked list in `C++`, as I know it, is structured such that there is a root node which holds no values but the first element in a list of nodes. The nodes which are in the linked list headed by the root node (all of which hold data, and a pointer to the next node in the list).

A simple list skeleton (with no mutators or accessors) may look something like this:

```
class List {
private:
    struct Node {
        int value;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* root;
public:
    List() {
        root = new Node;
        root->next = nullptr;
        root->val = 0;
    }
}
```

I would assume this all would mean that `root->next` would point to the first element in the list (meaning the root node is not the first element) correct?

Comment: There's no inherent reason the head node can't store useful data as well as a pointer to the next node.

Comment: It's implementation dependent. I've seen some done like that but I don't find it particularly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *head node* that isn't considered a regular node, can simplify <sup>(1)</sup>some list operations.

When there is one, it isn't considered part of the set of regular nodes, and if the list is abstracted, the head node is then usually not visible to client code.

Likewise one can have a *tail node*, but instead it's simpler to just use a *circular list*.

---

All that said, consider just using `std::list` where you need to insert or delete data without invalidating pointers to existing items.

And more in general, just use `std::vector` (except possibly for `vector<bool>`, where one might instead consider e.g. `deque<bool>`).

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> E.g. deleting the first node that satisfies some criterion.</sup>